# SKAudioNode has issues doing SKActions in Xcode 9b2

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction, xcode9, skaudionode

so i have a project that run perfectly fine on xcode 8 but when i am trying to run it on xcode 9b2 it crashes.

i am creating audionode:

```
let birdSound = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "fly.mp3")
```

add it to scene and it works.
but if i am doing actions like:

```
birdSound.run(SKAction.changeVolume(to: 0, duration: 0))
birdSound.run(SKAction.changePlaybackRate(to: 1.1, duration: 0))
```

it will crash with

> AURemoteIO::IOThread (14): EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,
>   subcode=0x0)

last debug lines are:

> 177: Failed to set processVolumeScalar on device. Error: 560947818 93:
>   ASSERTION FAILURE:

what is going on and why i cant do any SKActions on audio nodes?
any thoughts?

Comment: When are you creating the audio node? It may not be attached to the audio engine yet.

Comment: its inside a class. init has these SKActions. instance of a class is created inside of gamescene and in didMoveTo it is added to a scene

Comment: you can't do it during init,  the node is not attached to the scene yet, so there is no audio engine

Comment: ok i will try to make a func setup() with all the audio stuff and call it after i addChild it

Comment: you can check if the audio engine exists by `if let _ = scene?.audioEngine`

Comment: i encapsulated all audio stuff inside a method of this object class. and after i add this object to a scene i perform an audio engine exist check and setup audio. and it still crashes but works fine in xcode 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in xcode 9b5 it works fine :/ 
false alarm